Number of routes of Königsberg's Bridges problem in Christopher Moore's "The Nature of Computation"
This is supposed to be a very simple question.
In the Prologue of Christopher Moore's book "The Nature of Computation" (2011), page 3, the number of possible routes of the Königsberg problem is calculated as 2ⁿ with n=7.
Quote:

Assume for simplicity that each time we arrive on an island or a riverbank there are two different ways we could leave.  Then if there are n bridges to cross, a rough estimate for the number of possible walks would be 2ⁿ.

I have a hard time making sense of this "rough estimate".
What is the possible mental model behind it?

Do you mean. why it is power of instead of a multiple of?

I simply have absolutely no idea why 2^n amounts to a "simple estimate"...

It is really odd, because after one bridge one can only walk one another bridge.  And one bridge does not lead to all other https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Figure-shows-a-the-Koenigsberg-bridge-problem-and-b-the-corresponding-graphical-model_fig1_287687118 . But the formula was there, as far as I can remember, to check if one can walk all bridges once in a row. With that in mind you can manually try all 2^n routes.

Actually I think the notion of "possible walks" is not straightforward to me, because there is no acceptable route.  So what is being counted here?

In  long formula I guess it is just: you have 7 bridges to walk, and then again 7 bridges. So it is 2x2x2x2x2x2x2 yes or no. The formula is very condensed, because after you had 2^7 choices, you walk one bridge, and only have 2^6 choices. So isn`t the formula: 2^7 - 2^6 - 2^5 - 2^4 - 2^3 - 2^2 - 2 which yields 2? Then the map I linked does not even show 2 choices, but more. Depending on the place you are. What would be your formula?✨

Thanks!  I did some calculation with python (see my answer).

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [math.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

So I wrote a python code to actually enumerate all the possible unsuccessful "walks" a human would try (maybe with a pencil over the graph):
def get_remaining_paths(v, edges):
    paths = []
    for i,e in enumerate(edges):
        if v in e:
            edges_next = edges[:]
            edges_next.pop(i)
            if e[0] == v:
                vnext = e[1]
            else:
                vnext = e[0]
            paths_next = get_remaining_paths(vnext, edges_next)
            if len(paths_next) == 0:
                paths.append([(v, vnext)])
            else:
                for p in paths_next:
                    paths.append([(v, vnext)] + p)
    return paths
    
vertices = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
edges = [('A','B'), ('A','B'), ('A','C'), ('A','C'), ('A','D'), ('B','D'), ('C','D')]
all_paths = {v: get_remaining_paths(v, edges) for v in vertices}
all_paths_nums = {v: len(all_paths[v]) for v in vertices}
success = {v: any([len(p)==len(edges) for p in all_paths[v]]) for v in vertices}    
print(all_paths_nums)
print(success)

The output is
{'A': 108, 'B': 90, 'C': 90, 'D': 84}
{'A': False, 'B': False, 'C': False, 'D': False}

which means the number of possible unsuccessful routes starting from 'A' is 108, from 'B' is 90, from 'C' 90, and from 'D' 84.
So the total number of trials is 372.  Of course, all of them are unsuccessful.


Is the estimate the OP is referring to supposed to include 'unsuccessful' walks? What's an unsuccessful walk?

For the Konigsberg seven bridges problem, all trials are "unsuccessful" because it is well-known that there is no solution.  What I am simulating is what a person (without knowing Euler's reasoning and just want to do a brute-force search) would manually do.
